# How to wait until specific word is found in response in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, request, response, wait

The json response is:

```html
{
  "status": 11111,
  "data": {
    "mylist": 
    {
      "1": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "tId": 11
        }],
    
      "2": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "tId": 12
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "tId": 12
  
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "tId": 13,
        }
      ]
}
```

since server takes times to show this response, we want to wait until we see the values under "1" and under "2". How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add 2 [JSON Extractors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to store the values of `id` attributes below `1` and `2` into the relevant [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

   [image]

   [image]
2. Put the whole construction under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('1_matchNr') ?: 0  as int) == 0 && (vars.get('2_matchNr') ?: 0  as int) == 0,)}
   ```

   [image]
3. That's it, JMeter will repeat the request until there are results under `mylist` containing at least one `id` attribute

Comment: is that working for you? I added 2 json extractors as mentioned to store values of id attributes and added while controller for same request, what I see is, while loop is not executing at all.

Comment: that worked after jmeter was restarted. thank you!

Comment: Hi - I have a similar query. I am going to upload an asset and the response I am expecting when the asset processStatus is published. I have created a json extractor but I think in the whole controller, I am having problem writing groovy script.
I need to wait until the status is published.
${__groovy(vars.get('processStatus') == 'Published')}

Answer (score 0):

JMeter [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler downloads all of the data to mark request complete. Once downloaded, you can add different types of assertions like JSON Assertion, JSR223 Assertion or Response Assertion to validate different properties of response.
To best of my knowledge you cannot peak into data while it is streaming / downloading.